# Typescript variables/fields are always undefined when debugging in VS 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Why are the properties/field variables in Typescript are always undefined when debugging in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely debugging inside of arrow function, where *`this`* becomes **`_this`** in runtime.

So, just use **`_this.MyProperty`** in watch...

Read more about [Arrow Functions here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Comment: You mean it fails when using lambdas?

Comment: I do, but it seems ugly to use var _this = this. No offense but hmm.. ok. Thanks, I think i can use it. :)